# Power BI Embedded - Capture/Decode Bookmark State?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

When utilising Bookmarks with Power BI Embedded is it possible to capture/decode the state that it represents?

We plan to expose Bookmarks to our users however it would be nice if we could capture some sort of JSON/XML/? representaiton of the bookmark state as well so we can use this to understand what users are bookmarking and also protect again breaking bookmarks going forward.

Comment: Can you please share the purpose of decoding the state?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve bookmark information, you can utilize the [BookmarksManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/bookmarksmanager.bookmarksmanager) class.

Here's an example of how you can use it in your code:

```
const bookmarks = await report.bookmarksManager.getBookmarks();
console.log(bookmarks);
```

The above code will return an array of objects, each containing the display name, name, and state of the bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  

There are two main purposes for wanting to decode the state.

I want ot know what has been bookmarked to understand if a change to report is going to break existing bookmarks.

I also want to know what the state of the report is so I can better understand what users are doing via bookmarks. Why are the choosing to view the report in the bookmarked state, what view is valuable to them etc